# Python output printing more than once and function giving parameter not identified error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know this is pretty basic, but I am kind of stuck in a minor step. Noob to python, please excuse my ignorance.
Question is to generate all prime numbers **strictly** between 2 random user input numbers (which means first and 2nd numbers not included). Also, if there are no prime numbers between the 2 numbers, `"No Primes"` output should be printed.
My code:

```
Firstno=int(input("number1: "))
Secondno = int(input("number2: "))
for num in range(Firstno+1,Secondno -1):
  if num>1:
    for i in range (2,num):
      if (num%i) == 0:
        break 
      else:
        print(num)
```

This gives part of desired output, but `"No primes"` is not displayed. If I include `print("No primes")` in place of break statement and test with numbers `23` and `29`, `"No Primes"` output is repeated twice.
I also tried defining a function(with my little knowledge)

```
def is_prime(n):
  for i in range(x,n):
    if (n%i) == 0:
      return "No Primes"
  return True

Firstno=int(input("number1: "))
Secondno = int(input("number2: "))

for num in range(Firstno+1,Secondno -1):
  if is_prime(num):
    print(num)
```

Which I know is not right..because x is not defined. Please provide your suggestions on improving my code to get the desired output.

Comment: `Secondno-1` looks wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You Basically need to remove the `-1` from the line `for num in range(Firstno+1,Secondno -1):` to understand why look at code for inclusive range: `for num in range(Firstno,Secondno+1):`

Here is your first attempt code tidied up a little:

```
lower_boundry = int(input("Enter the lower boundry number: "))
upper_boundry = int(input("Enter the upper boundry number: "))

print("Prime numbers between", lower_boundry , "and", upper_boundry , "exclusive are:")

primes_found = []

for num in range(lower_boundry + 1, upper_boundry):
  if num > 1:
    for i in range(2,num):
      if (num % i) == 0:
        break
    else:
      primes_found.append(num)

if len(primes_found) > 0:
  print(primes_found)
else:
  print("No Primes")
```

**Example Usage with Primes in between:**

```
Enter the lower boundry number:  2
Enter the upper boundry number:  6
Prime numbers between 2 and 6 exclusive are:
[3, 5]
```

**Example Usage with No Primes in between:**

```
Enter the lower boundry number:  2
Enter the upper boundry number:  3
Prime numbers between 2 and 3 exclusive are:
No Primes
```

Try the above code [here!](https://repl.it/Kt3C/1)

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to include this criteria- The order of numbers entered should not matter. For example, if 5 and 12 were entered in that order, then 7 11 would print out. If 12 and 5 were entered in that order, then 7 11 would print out. But when I use the above code,  on entering 5 and 12, I get 7 ad 11, but when I enter 12 and 5, I get No primes output!

Comment: I corrected the code to this-below.(omitted first few lines coz of lack of space). It now satisfies all my criteria, I guess. Please let me know if there is any better way/ a shorter version of this code.

Comment: `primes_found = []
if lower_boundry < upper_boundry:
  for num in range(lower_boundry + 1, upper_boundry):
    if num > 1:
      for i in range(2,num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
          break
      else:
        primes_found.append(num)
    
else:
  for num in range(upper_boundry + 1, lower_boundry):
    if num > 1:
      for i in range(2,num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
          break
      else:
        primes_found.append(num)`